# Memcpy failing to copy from stream to float variable

Tags: c, sockets, memcpy

Im trying to send a struct through a socket, for this, im serializing and deserializing it

```
typedef struct pcb{
    uint16_t  id;
    uint16_t  tamano;
    uint8_t   pc;
    int       tp;       
    float     srt;
}t_pcb;
```

My problem comes when trying to rebuild the struct, specifically when trying to store the float value.

```
static void deserializar_header_PCB_KTC(void* stream, t_pcb* pcb, uint8_t *tamanoInstrucciones) {
    int offset = 0;


    memcpy(pcb->id, stream, sizeof(uint16_t));
    offset = sizeof(uint16_t);
    memcpy(pcb->tamano, stream+offset, sizeof(uint16_t));
    offset += sizeof(uint16_t);
    memcpy(pcb->pc, stream+offset, sizeof(uint8_t));
    offset += sizeof(uint8_t);
    memcpy(pcb->tp, stream+offset, sizeof(int));
    offset += sizeof(int);
    memcpy(pcb->srt,stream+offset, sizeof(float)); 
    offset += sizeof(float);
    memcpy(tamanoInstrucciones, stream+offset, sizeof(int));

    
}
```

the following error comes up:

```
src/protocolo.c:323:12: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘memcpy’
     memcpy(f, stream+offset, sizeof(float));
```

i already tested the communication using int type instead of float and it works properly. I considered multiplying the float value and use int type, but i would lose definition so im trying to find some other way.

if anyone could help me with this i would really appreciate it.

Serialization

```
static void* serializar_header_PCB_KTC(t_pcb* pcb) {
    void* stream = malloc(sizeof(op) + sizeof(int) + sizeof(uint16_t) * 2 + sizeof(uint8_t) * 2 + sizeof(float));
    void* pos    = stream;
    uint8_t tamanoInstrucciones = tamano_intrucciones_pcb(pcb);
    
    op cop = HEADER;

    memcpy(pos, &cop, sizeof(op));
    pos += sizeof(op);
    memcpy(pos, &pcb->id, sizeof(uint16_t));
    pos += sizeof(uint16_t);
    memcpy(pos, &pcb->tamano, sizeof(uint16_t));
    pos += sizeof(uint16_t);
    memcpy(pos, &pcb->pc, sizeof(uint8_t));
    pos += sizeof(uint8_t);
    memcpy(pos, &pcb->tp, sizeof(int));
    pos += sizeof(int);
    memcpy(pos, &pcb->srt, sizeof(float));
    pos += sizeof(float);
    memcpy(pos, &tamanoInstrucciones, sizeof(uint8_t));
    return stream;
}
```

Comment: Pass the addresses of the objects to `memcpy`, not their values. E.g., use `&f`, not `f`. You are probably also getting messages about the integer objects, although they may be warnings rather than errors. Pay attention to warning messages. In the future, prepare a [mre] when posting a question like this. That should be code that anybody can compile to reproduce the error message without any changes or additions. The code in your question now does not define any `f`, so you would have gotten an error message about that.

Comment: What is `f`? And why is it not instead copying into the struct field `&pcb->srt` like all the other copies?

Comment: i was using f as an auxiliar float to try some solutions, forgot to change it here. Sorry, already edited it

Comment: And how about the fact that you are incorrectly passing variables rather than the address of the variables to `memcpy`. Do you understand that that is a (or even *the*) major problem?

Comment: "I'm trying to send a struct through a socket": this is already a mistake. There are a dozen ways this can fail due to compiler differences at both ends. Don't use `struct`s as network protocols. Use network protocols as network protocols. Define yourself an application protocol in octets and write yourself a library to send and receive it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always use the adresses of the objects with memcpy. You are using the value and you need to send the pointer.. for example:

```
memcpy(&pcb->srt,stream+offset, sizeof(float));
```